# How to short half of the secondary winding to the bridge rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, bridge-rectifier, full-bridge

[image: How do I make half of the secondary winding shorted?]

How do I modify this circuit into a half-shorted one?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? If the secondary winding is (allegedly) half shorted, in effect it is fully shorted due to magnetic coupling. And the primary fuse blows. What do you hope to gain from doing this thing?

Comment: How would you solve the problem if it didn't ask you to short the winding? What effect does shorting the winding have on the transformer parameters? (Turn ratio, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Just like the instructions say:

[image]

Alternatively:

[image]

Note the red lines.  Those represent wires shorting out half of the secondary.

Comment: Output voltage zero, ripple frequency undefined.